# How I can pass terminal commands to a Mac from a PC on the command line?

Tags: windows, macos, bash, networking, command-line

I am trying to send bash commands to a mac uisng a PC, both machines are connected to the same network.
I have searched online, but was unable to find any viable solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.Install [Putty](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html)

2. Find your Mac's local ip address
3. Open Putty and choose SSH
4. Enter that ip address and press Open

Answer (score 1):

Install or enable an SSH server on the Mac, then use `ssh` from e.g. [PuTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/) to run commands.

```
plink -ssh machost echo "I am running on the server!"
```